# File.read "[Invalid encoding]" in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to read content of file in ruby
The following code works fine for most of files I tried, But for one of them fails to read the file due to **invalid encoding** problem.

The file contains `xml` string (is a `plist` file)

```
content_of_file = File.read(@path_to_file)
```

Also

```
content_of_file = File.read(@path_to_file, :encoding => 'utf-8')
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: We don't know which file you are trying to read ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan is a plist file

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded with `utf-8`? Have you tried to use another encoding (like `iso-8859-1`?)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101719/trouble-opening-plist-files-in-text-editor

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Thank you, The issue fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101719/trouble-opening-plist-files-in-text-editor

plist files are not necessarily plain text so they need to be run through a converter. Finder and Xcode (which has a plist editor) do this without telling the user

The binary format is documented in this C code so any application can convert it and someone has written a format description in English and more Apple documentation here but note that it references old paths in /Developer/Documentation

The command line program plutil can convert to and from XML

e.g. to view a binary property list in XML format on stdout:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o - <file name>
```

Also to convert a binary to a XML plist in place and then leave it so that the user program can read either.

```
plutil -convert xml1 <file name>
```